# Definition of bounded for sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Given some sequence of function $(f_n)$.

I am having trouble understanding what it means for a sequence of function to be bounded.

Does the bound depend on $n$ or $x$? I've done some research and I've seen  around $|f_n(x)| \leq M_n$ for some $M_n$ which I am assuming the bound depends on $n$. Is it wrong if I get a bound that depends on $x$ instead?

I know for a function to be bounded means: $\forall x\in S |f(x)| \leq M$ for some $M\in \mathbb{R}$.

A sequence to be bounded means: $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, |x_n| \leq K$ for some $K\in\mathbb{R}$.

Please help thanks!!!

Comment: To give this meaning, you need to specify a norm. Then "$f_n$ is a bounded sequence of functions (with respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|$)" means "$\|f_n\|$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers."

Comment: You can have pointwise boundedness where $\forall n \ |f_n(x)| \leq M(x)$. In other words, the bound depends on $x$. You could also have uniform boundedness $\forall x \in S  \ \forall n \ |f_n(x)| \leq M$. This is a stronger concept that implies to first one